# How to set Selected values using model list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UnitIOConfig[3].InputOffInput, Model.InputOffList, "Select Input")
```

Unable to set selected value using `m.UnitIOConfig[3].InputOffInput`. Can someone help with it?

Comment: Show your models: `UnitIOConfig` and `InputOffInput`

Comment: Show also your `method`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UnitIOConfig[3].InputOffInput, Model.InputOffList, "Select Input",new { @id = m.UnitIOConfig[3]})
```

**Example** :

drop-down has data like

```
<option value="1">abc</option>
<option value="2">pqr</option>
```

if you set value in @id=1 when drop-down is render it will automatically select record that has value=1.

i also have problem and i solved like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PoState, new SelectList(StateList, "Id", "abbreviation"), "-Select State-", new { @id = Model.PoState, @class = "PoState form-control" })
```

Comment: ok @Gowtham if you find this answer is acceptable for you.. please click on right sign :)